# python function not returning required output

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have this function:

```
def convert_resource_name(instanceresourcename, region):
    domain_to_zoneid = {'us.eec':'', 'uk.eec': '', 'br.eec':'Z304954'}
    domains = {'us-east-1': 'us.eec', 'eu-west-2':'us.eec', 'sa-east-1':'br.eec'}
    if instanceresourcename != None:
        for d, h in domain_to_zoneid.items():
            if instanceresourcename.endswith(d):
                return instanceresourcename
            else:
                if not instanceresourcename.endswith(d) and region in domains.keys():
                    return instanceresourcename+'.'+domains[region]
```

when I call the function `convert_resource_name('blabla.br.eec', 'sa-east-1')`
I get this output:

```
blabla.br.eec.br.eec
```

but if I call it `convert_resource_name('blabla.us.eec', 'us-east-1')`
it works just fine. returning
blabla.us.eec

the idea is servers have a naming convention of name.domainname, if servers are not named correctly I want to be able to append the domain name to the server name

Comment: What do you mean by works just fine? what is the expected output?

Comment: the idea is servers have a naming convention of name.domainname ie blabla.br.eec, if servers are not named correctly ie blabla I want to be able to append the domain name to the server name using the region to determine the right domain name to add, using the function it works fine for other regions but not for sa-east-1, if the correct server name is used it still adds the domain name

Comment: @Adamjaal5 can you post the complete code (including the `lambda_nadler()` function?. its difficult to understand the process flow

Comment: the complete code is too long to post here, if you can run the function I posted, you will understand what I am talking about, the problem I have figured out is that the for loop does not iterate through all the keys and values in the dictionary domain_to_zoneid = {'us.eec':' ', 'uk.eec': ' ', 'br.eec':'Z304954'}, it stops at the first key/value, I am yet to understand why that is

Comment: its impossible to run this code snippet alone. You must read these threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which explain how to **ask a question** and **how to make a reproducible example**.

Comment: never mind I figured it out, if you had just run the function you will understand what I was talking about, your directing me to go read threads doesn't make any sense as you simply don't understand the question